# How to handle local databases for rails applications and errors after rails project install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I am starting to learn rails, with a php and front end background. I created a new rails project and that was going well enough, until I downloaded another rails app off github and installed all dependencies and gems...anyway these problems have been my undoing for the last two days...I would really appreciate some clarification.

How exactly do you manage local databases for a development version as opposed to those external databases for a live version?

Will Rails build a local database automatically after an application is imported from Github for instance? Or does one have to be created manually, also should it have the same authentication credentials that the downloaded uses to talk to its database?

Also, after I downloaded PostgreSQL and its gem, I can no longer start rails server for my old rails project, or for my new one for that matter, both get these errors:

gems/actionpack-3.0.16/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:98: warning: already initialized constant PDF
gems/activerecord-3.0.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `initialize': FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist (PGError)

Comment: You need to provide little more details..

Which operating system are you using? I can guess you're using postgres, but you probably need to provide contents of `config/database.yml` (note remove the passwords) and may be `Gemfile` for start.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using postgresql (which possibly shared by several applications), and in my understanding, two rails applications usually do not share namespaces other than database, I guess you've not modified `config/database.yml` file.

By convention, the default development database name is `development`, so, if you haven't touch the configuration file, the two applications share same database options, cause conflicts.

I usually modify the database name to `development_SomeApplicationName` (replace `SomeApplicationName` with some meaning application name to differentiate database name) just after creating new application.